# Untar a file over multiple directories/drives

Tags: tar, data-recovery, archive

I have a tar.gz file that when uncompressed will use 2 TB of data. On my machine I have 1.5 TB free on one drive and 1.2 TB free on another. I would like to untar this large archive over these two drives. I don't mind how the data is split as long as the data is present on these 2 drives.

Is this possible?

The top level directories in the tar archive are numerically numbered from 00000 to 99999.

Comment: Are the data evenly distributed between the directories?

Answer (score 2):

To split it by halves, based on your given directory names and presuming that your data are evenly distributed therein:

```
tar -C /path/to/mount1 xf /path/to/tarball.tgz {00000..49999}
tar -C /path/to/mount2 xf /path/to/tarball.tgz {50000..99999}
```

Just as when creating tarballs, you give it a list of files to archive; when unrolling tarballs, you give it a list of files to extract.  `-C` tells `tar` what the working directory of the extract operation should be.

Comment: So just to clarify, `{00000..49999}` would really mean actual filenames or file name patterns that would match about half of the files?  In practice, the OP could do a `tar tvf tarball.tgz` and look for which files to place where... and some trial and error.

Comment: This looks really good. Will this work with wildcards e.g. `{0*..4*}`? Will it also work if I had archives where there was a path in front of it, e.g. `{./some/nest/0*.../some/next/4*`?

Comment: `{0..9}` would expand to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` before being handed to `tar`.  You cannot use wildcards in brace expansions, so far as I am aware.  However, you can use wildcards in the paths to the actual tarballs, and in the lists of files to extract.  That said, `tar f` expects _one_ file name to be provided which would be the tarball upon to perform the operation.  To work on multiple tarballs, you'd want to perhaps iterate a `for` loop across the results of a `find` that returns the tarballs in question.

Comment: Less onerous, however is wildcards in the target filenames, e. g. `tar xf /path/to/tarball.tgz {00000.49999}/batch*` would only catch files and subdirectories matching the glob `batch*` within the numerical top-level directories.

Comment: Some `tar` commands have a `--wildcards` option to specify patterns of file to extract.